# Can only connect to the public container of CloudKit through wifi, but not cellular

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

There is a real lack of documentation and information in general out there regarding the public container of CloudKit. I'm having an issue where data cannot be sent while a device is on its cellular network, but works perfectly fine when connected to Wifi.

```swift
let publicCloudDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [exampleRecord], recordIDsToDelete: nil)
let operationConfiguration = CKOperation.Configuration()

operationConfiguration.allowsCellularAccess = true
operationConfiguration.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
operation.configuration = operationConfiguration

operation.perRecordProgressBlock = {(record, progress) in
    print(progress)
}

operation.perRecordCompletionBlock = {(record, error) in
    print("Upload complete")
}

publicCloudDatabase.add(operation)
publicCloudDatabase.save(exampleRecord) { [unowned self] record, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("public cloud database error: \(error)")
    } else {
        print("Sucessfully uploaded to Public Cloud DB")
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error that says:

> CKError 0x281ff9ec0: "Network Unavailable" (3/NSURLErrorDomain:-1009); "The Internet connection appears to be offline."

when the cellular connection is definitely not the issue on my device.

Comment: You are not making a URL request, are you?

Comment: Isn't the CloudKit API doing that for us in `CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if this might be a setting on the device. Have you checked that **iCloud Drive** is allowed to use cellular data?

On your iPhone/iPad, go to `Settings` > `Cellular` > `iCloud Drive` (way down at the bottom; make sure it's turned on).

Comment: wow I've been struggling with this for the past few days. Thank you so much

Comment: Is there a way to check if the user has this settings turned on?

Comment: I don't think there is, no. You are just going to have to watch for the network connection error then show the user a message that tells them there is no Internet (and that maybe they should check their settings).

Comment: We have been experiencing this same issue and the iCloud Drive was enabled. I'm sill looking for the reason, is there any other possible cause?